# PHPmailer: Send from form

Tags: php, phpmailer

Alright, I have my form (first snippet of code), and I am trying to use PHPmailer to send it. However, it sends the message without any of the information from the actual form. I am pretty lost with how to get this to work.

```
<form action="send_form_email.php" method="post" id="ContactForm">
                    <fieldset>
              <p class="email">magazines/newspapers</p>
                        <ol>
                            <li>
                                <label for=name>Name</label>
                                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="name" required autofocus>
                            </li>


                            <li>
                                <label for=email>Email</label>
                                <input id="email" name="email" type=email placeholder="example@domain.com" required>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <label for=telephone>Phone</label>
                                <input id=telephone name=telephone type=tel placeholder="Eg. 888-555-5555" required>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                            <label for="comments">note</label> 
                <textarea name=comments type=text placeholder="enter your comments" required></textarea>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                            <label for="file">File</label>
                            <input id="file" type="file" name="file" />
                            </li>

                        </ol>
                    </fieldset>

              <fieldset>
                        <button type=submit>submit</button>
                    </fieldset>

                </form>
```

Mail Script:

```
require("mail/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->Host = "localhost";               
$mail->From = "xxxxxx@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName  =  "Your Name";
$mail->AddAddress("xxxxxxx@gmail.com");


$mail->Subject = "Feedback form results";
$mail->Body = $comments;
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo 'Message was not sent.';
   echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
   echo 'Thank you for your feedback.';
}
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $comments = $_POST['telephone'] ;
    $phone = $_REQUEST['comments'] ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so step one (optional) is to collect the posted variables into local variables - **BEFORE** you get into the  `$mail=new PHPMailer()...` bit.  This isn't necessary for the limited code fragment you provide, but you might use them somewhere else.

```
$name = $_POST['name'] ;
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$telephone = $_REQUEST['telephone'] ;
$comments = $_POST['comments'] ;
```

And now, change the `$mail->Body = $comments;` line to:

```
$mail->Body="
Name: $name
Email: $email
Telephone: $telephone
Comments: $comments";
```

And as *ngroot* points out; to add an attachment:

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
```

... which you can call multiple times for multiple attachments.  Because of the way form-uploads work (files get stored in a temporary space) you need to use this `tmp_name` sub variable.  You'll also need to add multipart form encoding to allow file uploads, so the form line should read:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="send_form_email.php" method="post" id="ContactForm"  >
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're setting the $comments variable *after* sending the message.

Comment: O, thanks.. Very dumb question. But how do I send multiple "variables". Right now $comments is set to telephone. But I do need email, telephone, comments, and even a file upload.

Comment: What do you want the resulting email to look like for a given email address, telephone #, comments, etc. to look like?

Comment: Name
email
number
comment
file attachment

Comment: So, as Rudi noted below, just set the body to that:
`$mail->Body="Name: $_POST['name'] Email: $_POST['email'] Number: $_POST['telephone'] Comments: $_POST['comments']";`

Unless you want to stick the contents of the uploaded file into the message inline, you'd probably want to add a call after setting the body along the lines of
  
    `$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);`

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the variables after trying to send the mail. Also, I don't see a form input named `message`. However, I do see one named `file` though the form's enctype is not set. So there are many errors that need fixing.

Not sure what you're trying to do but it seems you don't need both `comments` and `message`. Remove `message` from the sending script and remove `file` from the html form to see if you can get it working like this. Also move the variable assignments from the bottom of the sending script to the top.

Comment: Thanks webbiedave. I did move it up to the top and that fixed everything. Well, it does send the email with the $comments data. However, I need email, telephone, as well as a file (using a file upload input) to be sent as well. Sorry, I am kind of new to all of this.