# Setup PHP mailer, but still not working. What did I do wrong?

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I am trying to setup php mailer to send me an email when someone fills out my form with the information.
Currently its a one page site on the file "index.php"

Here is my php:

```
  <?php

  include("includes/class.phpmailer.php");

  $mail = new PHPMailer;

  $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
  $mail->addAddress("myemail@gmail.com");     // Add a recipient
  $mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);

  $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML

  $mail->Subject = 'Message From ' . $name;

  $mail->Body    = "
  <h2>Message Details</h2>              
  <p>Name: {$name} </p>
  <p>Email: {$email} </p>
  <p>Phone: {$phone} </p>
  ";
   ?>
```

Please note I removed my email for privacy.

Below is my form on the same "index.php" file

```
    <form id="contact" method="post" action="index.php">
    <ul>
    <h2>Contact</h2>
   <li><input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"></li>
    <li><input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address"  value="<?php echo $email; ?>"></li>
    <li><input type="phone" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>"></li>
    <li><textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message">    </textarea></li>
    <li><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"></li>
    </ul>
    </form>
```

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why this isnt working, and would appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: Where are you handling the `POST` requests?

Comment: you mean where the phpmailer code is? That would be in the same file. The php code is above the opening <html> tag while the form is inside the contents of my html tags.

Comment: It would really help if you looked at the examples provided with PHPMailer. They provide reliable, tested starting pounts for many common scenarios - you're not the first to want to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this form to work you would need to add

```
$mail->send()
```

There are many form templates available if you simple google, or use these forums plenty of simalar questions about forms etc.

The simplest way to parse your fields would be, you can read up about $_POST here http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

You may find this topic useful to have a read through aswell, will give you more clarity on sending form data via phpmailer.

[PHPmailer: Send from form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603752/phpmailer-send-from-form)

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the `POST` request, here's one way to do  that:

```
   if(!empty($_POST['name'] && !empty($_POST['email'] && !empty($_POST['phone']){

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];

    include("includes/class.phpmailer.php");
    //the rest of you code ...
    //and finally $mail->Send()

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
    echo "Message sent!";
    }

    }
```

---

Notes:

Take a look at some [PHPMailer examples](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples)

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.php`, execute the email only when you have valid POST values. Also, I don't see you actually sending the email via the `$mail->send()` method.

It should be something like this:

```
if (count($_POST) > 0 && isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    include("includes/class.phpmailer.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
    $mail->addAddress("myemail@gmail.com");     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);

    $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = 'Message From ' . $name;

    $mail->Body    = "
        <h2>Message Details</h2>              
        <p>Name: {$name} </p>
        <p>Email: {$email} </p>
        <p>Phone: {$phone} </p>
    ";
}
```

Comment: I don't see the post requests being parsed either. PS: I didn't down voted you.

Answer (score 0):

To actually send the message, call the Send() function after you have the Subject, Body, addAddress, etc:

```
if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont see

```
$mail->send()
```

but i see no end of php script.haven't you forgot on that?

if you have even that, set `$SMTPDebug` to more than 0 and look for phpmailer log for errors

Comment: The ending `?>` in PHP is not needed if there is no static content after it. In fact it's regarded as an anti-pattern to use it as you may inadvertently have extra white space after the closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still not able to send emails you will need to look into your hosting companies email settings on your server. A lot of times you'll need to check your `smtp` setting if you're using `gmail smtp` which is popular.

You may need to call them and get some support on why you're not able to send email. This is a common issue.

Below is an example of `gmail SMTP` setting with phpmailer.

```
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
// 1 = errors and messages
// 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 587;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "yourusername@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";            // GMAIL password
```